# vim change multiline html tags with vim-surround

Tags: vim

I would like, using vim-surround to convert this

```
            <p>
            ^currsor
              Issues reported by users from the
              <a href="https://re.fr"> https://re.fr</a>
              they will create an issue.
            </p>
```

into that

```
            <h1 class="important">
              Issues reported by users from the
              <a href="https://re.fr"> https://re.fr</a>
              they will create an issue.
            </h1>
```

I've been using in command mode: `cs<<h1 class="important">` and I get

```
            <h1 class="important">p</h1>
            ^currsor
              Issues reported by users from the
              <a href="https://re.fr"> https://re.fr</a>
              they will create an issue.
            </p>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can just do ...

`cst<h1 class="important">`

"change surrounding tag "

Comment: Yes and no. Yes, because `cst` is the right command to use in this case. No, because `cst` is provided by Surround.

Answer (score 1):

And now i have surround to work:

`3VS<h1>`

will do the trick for you

Comment: I don't found what 3VS is ?

Comment: `3 = no of lines`

`V = Visual`

`S = (wrap) Selection`

Answer (score 0):

Without using the surround plugin i would do this:

```
:%s/p>/h1>
```

Comment: I agree, let's put a more general exemple